# VBA: Quicksort Descending

Tags: vba, quicksort

How do I convert [this](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/string-manipulation.htm) to descending? I gave it a try and it worked on a smaller sample but I just want to make sure I got it down properly. This is my edited version of the [original](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/string-manipulation.htm):

```
Private Sub QuickSortByAge(arr() As Integer, inLow As Integer, inHi As Integer)
    Dim pivot   As Integer
    Dim tmpSwap As Integer
    Dim tmpLow  As Integer
    Dim tmpHi   As Integer

    tmpLow = inLow
    tmpHi = inHi

    pivot = arr((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

    While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)
        While (arr(tmpLow) > pivot And tmpLow < inHi) 'converted sign
            tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        Wend

        While (pivot > arr(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow) 'converted sign              
            tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
        Wend

        If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
            tmpSwap = arr(tmpLow)
            arr(tmpLow) = arr(tmpHi)
            arr(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
            tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
            tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
        End If

    Wend

    If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSortByAge arr, inLow, tmpHi
    If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSortByAge arr, tmpLow, inHi

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code works as intended and you've tested it and you want to know if it could be implemented better, or improved in any way, you should head over to [codereview.se]. If there's no specific problem with your code, the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Depending on the number of items being sorted, you may want a 32 bit integer instead of 16. E.g. use Long.

Comment: @RyanWildry This actually solved the problem I was having when I tested out the code further.

Answer (score -1):

The algorythm was original to sort Ascending.

These line were added to reverse the flow.

```
tmpLow = inLow
tmpHi = inHi
```

I created a test to fill an `arr(1000000)` and then sorted it using `QuickSortByAge`. When it crashed I inspected opened up the local variables window and found that the value of `tmpHi` was 16385.  The Max array size is 16384 on my machine.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arr(16384) As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Int((Rnd * 1000) + 1)
    Next

    QuickSortByAge arr, 0, UBound(arr)

    For Each c In arr
        Debug.Print c
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub QuickSortByAge(arr() As Integer, inLow As Integer, inHi As Integer, Optional bDescending As Boolean)
    Dim pivot As Integer
    Dim tmpSwap As Integer
    Dim tmpLow As Integer
    Dim tmpHi As Integer


        tmpLow = inLow
        tmpHi = inHi


    pivot = arr((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

    While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)
        While (arr(tmpLow) > pivot And tmpLow < inHi)    'converted sign
            tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
        Wend

        While (pivot > arr(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)    'converted sign
            tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
        Wend

        If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
            tmpSwap = arr(tmpLow)
            arr(tmpLow) = arr(tmpHi)
            arr(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
            tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
            tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
        End If

    Wend

    If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSortByAge arr, inLow, tmpHi, bDescending
    If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSortByAge arr, tmpLow, inHi, bDescending

End Sub
```